# c# show only Month / Day

Tags: c#

I have the following

```
    string.Format("{0:MM/dd}",item.ActDate)
```

Not sure whey it still shows it in 01/09/2012. I just need for it to show as 01/09.
Any idea?

Comment: Please show a short but complete program which demonstrates the problem - and demonstrates the type of `ActDate`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

is ActDate a datetime?

```
item.ActDate.ToString("MM/dd")
```

Answer (score 0):

What datatype is ActDate?  If it is a DateTime, that should work fine.  If it is a String, you should format it correctly when you casted it to that string.

Answer (score 0):

That code definitely *won't* show the year, assuming `ActDate` really is a `DateTime`:

```
string text = string.Format("{0:MM/dd}", DateTime.Today);
Console.WriteLine(text); // Prints 02/21
```

Of course if `ActDate` is already a string ("01/09/2012") then that formatting won't do anything - it'll just leave it as it is. If that's the case, you'll need to parse it to a `DateTime` first. (Or use straight string manipulation, but I don't think that's a good idea.)

Using `item.ActDate.ToString("MM/dd")` (possibly specifying an appropriate culture) is neater code, but basically it's not going to change the result from your current code. (EDIT: If it compiles. If it doesn't compile, that would again suggest that it's not a `DateTime`...)

Comment: I suppose your hypothesis about `ActDate` being a string is correct.  In that case, `item.ActDate.ToString("MM/dd")` *would* change the result compared to the current code; the code would no longer compile, exposing the faulty logic.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
item.ActDate.ToString("MM/dd");
```